# Magento 2.4 Track this shipment link error on open Popup

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, shipment-tracking, magento2.4.0

I was trying to implement a custom shipping label programmatically but I'm getting error below:

```
Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\Phrase::getTracking()....
```

I am using `\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentTrackInterfaceFactory` to create tracking and my custom carrier is extending `AbstractCarrier`.

Everything seems to work fine except for the links that open the pop up. Links are:

> `Track this shipment` and
> `Track order`

both under **Shipping & Handling Information** and **Shipping and Tracking Information**.

**Update:** I found this on [github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/27195#issuecomment-643437645) upon googling but I don't think the solution will work for me as this is a custom module.

Comment: @ShoaibMunir no worries. one last, can I pass additional param to `getTrackingInfo` ?

Comment: No you can't, `getTrackingInfo` function should follow `\Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface` parent function, which has only one parameter i.e `$trackings`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your custom module's Carrier Model you need to add a function `getTrackingInfo`

location of the file would be something like this:

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Carrier/YourFile.php
```

In this file add a the function

```
public function getTrackingInfo($trackings)
{
    $result = $this->_trackFactory->create();
    $tracking = $this->_trackStatusFactory->create();

    $tracking->setCarrier($this->_code);
    $tracking->setCarrierTitle("Carreir Title");
    $tracking->setTracking($trackings);
    $tracking->setUrl('http://www.example.com/?cn=' . $trackings); //This is tracking URL

    $result->append($tracking);

    return $tracking;
}
```

where `$this->_trackFactory` is the instance of `\Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\ResultFactory`
and `$this->_trackStatusFactory` is the instance of `\Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\Result\StatusFactory`

This should resolve the error that you are facing

Comment: Simple and accurate solution. Thanks!