# magento 2 - how to add tracking number and detail link open new window set in sale order grid

Tags: magento2, order-status, order-grid, shipment-tracking

how to add tracking number and detail new window link set in sale order grid like below

[image]

Comment: I've run into this before, you can check here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/326379/74200

Comment: link add on order grid